# Build a nested list using JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JSON that creates a menu:

```
{
    "menu": {
        "id": "organisation-201",
        "class": "list",
        "content": {
            "menuitem": [{
                "text": "New Journal Entry",
                "title": "New Journal Entry",
                "href": "/Organisations/201/NewJournalEntry",
                "liClass": "",
                "icon": "icon test"
            }, {
                "text": "View People",
                "title": "View People",
                "href": "/Organisations/201/People",
                "liClass": "",
                "icon": "icon test"
            }, {
                "text": "Edit",
                "title": "Edit",
                "href": "/Organisations/201/Edit",
                "liClass": "sep",
                "icon": "icon test"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

And then using jQuery we build it like: (Note: I call the json using `$.ajax` but not shown it here!)

```
// Build the menu
var ul = $("<ul/>").attr("id", data.menu.id).addClass(data.menu.class);

// For each menu item
$.each(data.menu.content.menuitem, function () {
    var li = $("<li/>").appendTo(ul).addClass(this.liClass);
    var anchor = $("<a/>").appendTo(li).attr("href", this.href).attr("title", this.title);

    var span = $("<span/>").appendTo(anchor).addClass(this.icon).html(this.text)
});
```

Okay so what I'm trying to do is build a nested menu structure so for example I could have mark-up like:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Link 2.1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Link 2.2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What would the best way to do this be? Baring in mind that they're might not always be a submenu... I've thought about putting extra parameters in the menuitem but the nested menus could be 2-3 levels deep so it needs to be flexible. Any ideas suggestions and code examples would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you modify your JSON to show a 3 level menu?

Comment: Well that's also part of my question as I'm wondering what the best way to structure something like would be.

Answer (score 0):

you should add to each menuitem object a property called ex "content" which may contain additional sub-menu items

```
{"menu": {
    "content" : {
        "menuitem": [{
            "text": "New Journal Entry",
            ...
            "content" : {
                "menuitem":[{
                    "text": "Submenu"
                    ..
                            }]
                        }
                    ]}
                }
        }
}}
```

than you could use nested .each() functions for parsing you json

Answer (score 0):

[Here's what i made](http://jsfiddle.net/fskreuz/CKAwS/2/). it parses multiple levels (up to 3 in the demo, but it can do more actually)

```
{"menu": {
    //attributes for the <ul>
    "attributes": {               
        "id": "organisation-201",
        "class": "list"
    },
    //<li>'s
    "items": [{     
        //<li> attributes               
        "attributes": {},
        //<a> attributes
        "link": {
            "text": "New Journal Entry",
            "title": "New Journal Entry",
            "href": "/Organisations/201/NewJournalEntry"
        },
        //<li> icon
        "icon": "icon test",
        //submenu of the same structure
        "menu": ...
    }]
}​}
```

and this structure is parsable by this compact script:

```
var menu = (function menuBuilder(menu) {
    var $menu = $('<ul/>').attr(menu.attributes);
    $.each(menu.items, function(itemIndex, itemData) {
        var $item = $('<li/>').attr(itemData.attributes).appendTo($menu);
        var $link = $('<a/>').appendTo($item);            
        $.each(itemData.link, function(linkKey, linkVal) {
            if (linkKey === 'text') {$link.text(linkVal);} 
            else {$link.attr(linkKey, linkVal);}
        });
        if (itemData.hasOwnProperty('menu')) {
            $item.append(menuBuilder(itemData.menu));
        }
    });
    return $menu;
}(json.menu));

$('body').append(menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need to create dynamic html from data in javscript, I like making hidden "template" divs, using a function to fill the template with the data of the item, then using, with jquery, something like  `$real_list.append( $item_template.html() );` to build the actual html.
So for your menu I would try something like this.

```
<div id="menu_level_template" style="display_none">
  <ul class="menu_level">

  </ul>
</div>

<div id="menu_item_template" style="display_none">
  <li>
    <a href=""></a>
  </li>
</div>
```

js

```
function parse_menu(menu_level_object, $destination)
{
  var $level_template=$('#menu_level_template');  
  $level_template.find('ul').html('');  //reset the template

  fill_menu_template_with_menu_level_data();

  $destination.append( $level_template.html() );

  var $current_level_ul = get_ul_of_just_appended_html();
  var menu_items = get_menu_items( menu_level_object );
  $.each(menu_items,function(index,menu_item)
  {
     parse_item( menu_item, $current_level_ul );
  });
}

function parse_item( menu_item, $destination )
{
  var $item_template=$('#menu_item_template');
  $item_template.html(' '); //clear the template

  fill_item_template_with_data();

  $destination.append( $item_template.html() );

  if( has_submenu( menu_item ) )
  {
    var submenu= get_submenu( menu_item );
    parse_menu( submenu, $destination );
  }
}

parse_menu(menu_data, $root_menu_location);
```

When yo use $element.html() it takes the contents, not the tag itself, so the "divs" of the template are never copied.  Recursive to handle any level of menus.